# how to limit the number of page versions in AEM 6.2?

Tags: aem, aem-6

In sidekick, I can create as many **versions of a page** and can restore as well. 
What I am looking for is, **how to limit the number** of "*creation of page versions*" . Suppose, after 5 versions I want to display an error - "*more versions are not allowed*".

I followed the link for reference but no luck: http://www.wemblog.com/2012/08/how-to-work-with-version-in-cq.html

You have to create a **osgi:Config within repository for this (com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.VersionManagerImpl**).

You can control number of version created by activation by setting **versionmanager.maxNumberVersions** property.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no pro-active way to stop any versions from being created in the AEM repository. The configuration you are referring to is from: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/version-purging.html#Version Manager

> versionmanager.maxNumberVersions (int, default 5)
>   on purge, any version older than the n-th newest version will be removed. If this value is less than 1, purging is not performed based on the number of versions

This is the setting for version purge task which retains a maximum of **n** number of versions after purging where **n** is the number defined in the above config.

A preemptive version disabler won't work as versions are created from background tasks like workflows asynchronously. These tasks will fail without any feedback to user which will be problematic in most scenarios.

If you want to change the sidekick and disallow version creation, then you will have to rewrite core logic of the UI which can be a big task. Version Purging is the recommended way to setup your instance to limit the number of versions.